# MySQL issue with RAND() and 1 DESC?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, sql-order-by

I have created a gallery using a database. All the images are showing randomly on Home page. Now I need to add a new "Latest"`index.php/latest.php` category to my navigation bar.

I'm using infinite scroll and a little trick to order randomly`$rand=date("i");`.

**Question:** `ORDER BY 1 DESC` is not working on `index.php/latest.php`, because I have ordered by randomly on the Home page. How could I order by descending order on the Latest page without changing the Home page order?

> index.php

```
<?php

include ("sqli.php");
$rand=date("i");

$seed=($rand);
$per_page = 9;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {

    $page = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
    $page=1;
}

$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

$query = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY RAND($rand) LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";

$result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);

<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

?>

<div id="gallery here"></div>

<?php> } ?>
```

> latest.php

```
<?php

include ("sqli.php");
$per_page = 9;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {

    $page = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
    $page=1;
}

$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

$query = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";

$result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
?>

<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

?>

<div id="gallery here"></div>

<?php> } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set order by createdAt field(by your date field) in last.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result. Now I have a php warning for `<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>` this line.

Comment: Do you have "createdAt" field into your database table? Please try to change  field name "createdAt" on your field name where you save date of creation.

Comment: Yes @Anna still I have a same issue.Latest.php page work without any issue if I will change Home page to `ORDER BY 1 DESC`. But I need to order by descending on the Latest page without changing the Home page order.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by me. This issue related to infinite-scroll navigation. I hope my PHP code will help to someone. You can use this PHP code for [jQuery Infinite-Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) pagination. I'm here if you have any question. Thanks all.